# Flask 404 on Dreamhost

Tags: python, http, flask, passenger, dreamhost

I am using Flask on Dreamhost. I (mostly) followed the instruction posted here https://mattcarrier.com/flask-dreamhost-setup/. I was able to successfully set up pages and direct urls to those pages, etc.

Now I want to be able to set a 404 page. I set the error handler using @app.errorhandler. The only problem is that it just returns a standard Apache 500 error page if I go to any page that doesn't have a URL set. Is this because of how Dreamhost has Apache setup? The public (static) folder is at the top level. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here - http://blog.tuxcoder.com/2011/9/8/dreamhost_python_wsgi/

> If you plan to do any active development on the Dreamhost side, this step will simplify your efforts. Werkzeug comes with a really nice debugging engine, but it does not work with the Dreamhost configuration by default.
>   or example, if you have a simple Python coding error in your app, it will result in the following:
>
> [image: default error page of werkzeug]
>
> In this mode, you're out of luck. The only option is to startup a local server where you can go back and test the app. In some cases it might be a big effort just to replicate the bug.
>
> With the Werkzeug Debugger enabled and patched, you'll get a much nicer output:
>
> [image: werkzeug debugger]

Here is what it says on the Dreamhost Wiki http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Flask (in `passenger_wsgi.py`:

> ```
> # Uncomment next two lines to enable debugging
> # from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
> # application = DebuggedApplication(application, evalex=True)
> ```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that using the Werkzeug debugger on a public server creates a huge security hole.

Comment: True, I'm using this for debugging only -  on a separate domain I'm using for development

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try creating the file "missing.html" at the top level.

source: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Creating_custom_error_pages

Edit:
To setup an error handling page from Flask itself, you do this:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/

My thought is that you are getting the 500 error because Flask/Python is crashing. Do you have debugging turned on? How is your routing setup?

Comment: Even then, it would be displaying a 500 error when all I want is a 404

Comment: I have a feeling that the 500 error is coming because Flask/Python is crashing.

Comment: But what is causing it to crash?